# JSPExpression Language reading value from bean

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a login servlet which is the begin of the workflow

**LoginServlet.java**

```
doGet(...) throws ... {
    User user = new User();
    request.setAttribute("user", user);
    ServletContext sc = this.getServletContext();
    RequestDispatcher rd = sc.getRequestDispatcher("/Login.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

User is a bean used to hold data for now I have added both username and password as public just to understand. Im not sure if I can accesss these directly from JSP later

```
**User.java**
public class User {
    public String username;
    public String password;
}

**Login.jsp**
...
<form action="/ProfileServlet" method = "post">
    Username: <input type="text" value = "${user.username}"/>
    Submit: <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
...
```

So Instead of writing request.getAttribute("user").I have used the bean directly, not sure If I'm missing it here

```
**ProfileServlet.java**
protected void doPost(..)..{
User user = (User) request.getAttribute("user");
System.out.println("logged in user "+user.username);
}
```

Im trying to printout the username given. But somehow im getting nullpointerexception since request doesn't has attribute user.

I tried for examples for EL across web but couldn't find the satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 0):

The Expression Language uses getters and setters of a bean to access the properties.
The Properties can be even omitted and not defined at all.

The JSP and the EL are compiled to java code when the page is requested. In the generated java class the EL like `${user.username}` are transformed to `user.getUsername();`.

**User.java**

```
public class User {

    // the properties are optional

    private String username;
    private String password;

    // the getters are needed for reading of bean values

    public String getUsername() {
        // the return data could be some on the fly calculation, DB data, etc
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        // the return data could be some on the fly calculation, DB data, etc
        return password;
    }

    // the setters are for write access

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        // do something with the data, store it 
        // usually 
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        // do something with the data, store it
        // usually
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

The Getter and Setter names in the Bean and the EL-access-names follow some rules.

[The JavaBean Documentation is here](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf).

In some cases there are issues for properties in CamelCase with leading lower/upper letters.
More here:  [jsp:setproperty property=“*” not set all properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41123125/jspsetproperty-property-not-set-all-properties/41127160#41127160)

The other issue is the life/scope of an attribute.

In the (Login)Servlet you define the user attribute in the request scope and forward to the JSP.
After the JSP is processed, the user attribute is no more accessible. The request was responded. The end.

When the Login.jsp is submitted by user,this is an other request.
The ProfileServlet can access the formfield data using `request.getParameter("username")`.

The the user name and password are validated you can set an `user` the attribute to the session in order to have easy access in all following pages.